# Ruby Liquid templating nested hashes

Tags: ruby, erb, liquid

I have a nested hash:

```
{
  :KeyA => {
            :KeyB => "hello",
            :KeyC => {
                      :KeyD => "foo",
                      :KeyE => "bar"
                    }
          }
}
```

if I pass this to ERB I can do:

```
<%= config[:KeyA][:KeyC][:KeyD] %>
```

and get:

```
foo
```

However this doesnt work with Liquid :(

If I do:

```
Liquid::Template.parse(template).render(Hash["config" => myhash ])
```

I can do:

```
{{ config }}
```

and I get the pseudojson from above printed out, but

```
{{ config[:KeyA] }}
```

results in nothing :(

Does Liquid support this? If not what alternatives are there to ERB that do support this, and preferably allow me to customise the replacement tags (I cant use ERB because im running it on an ASP file which contains `<%` markup)

Comment: In the first code block, do you mean `:KeyA` rather than `KeyA`?

Comment: ah well spotted, and the others. *corrected*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used [erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.html) in the end

Answer (score 1):

Use dots,

e.g.:

```
Liquid::Template.parse("{{ a[0].b[2].c  }}").render('a' => [{'b'=>[1,2,{'c'=>33}]}])
```

Output:

```
 => "33"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (import a yaml object to a hash) and it was impossible to work fine. Finally I decided to use erubis. There's life beyond of Liquid and also another template enngines. You can read an excellent post at http://www.hokstad.com/mini-reviews-of-19-ruby-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

use `deep_stringify_keys!`

Liquid seems to have problems with symbols as keys for nested objects.